# Using the same mysqli connection ($conn=mysqli_connect) multiple times gives errors

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using the mysqli functions `(mysqli_connect, mysqli_select_db, mysqli_query)` to call 1 select query and 2 stored procedures.

It seems that when I am using the same `$connection` (returned by `mysqli_connect`) multiple times, I am getting the following error message: `"Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in..."`

Below is my code:

```
<?php
$server="localhost";
$user="user";
$pass="pass";
$db="db";

$connection=mysqli_connect("$server","$user","$pass");
mysqli_select_db($connection, "$db") or die('Unable to select database.');

//First SELECT using $connection
$query=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT item_name FROM items ORDER BY item_name DESC");    

While ($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_NUM))
{
  $complete_result[] = $result[0];
  $total_rows = $total_rows + 1;
}   

//CALL to first sp using $connection
$query2 = mysqli_query($connection, "CALL sp_check_edits_remaining()");

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $edits_remaining = $row2['edits_remaining'];
} // End while

//CALL to second sp using $connection   
$query3 = mysqli_query($connection, "CALL sp_edit_data");

while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {);
    $edits_id = $row3['id'];
} // End while

?>
```

Like I described, when I call the second sp, the above code gives me the error message mentioned above. (Please note that the connection is never closed.)

However, when I create another connection and provide it to the second sp call, this error disappears. This is shown in the code below

```
$connection2=mysqli_connect("$server","$user","$pass");
mysqli_select_db($connection2, "$db") or die('Unable to select database.');

//CALL to second sp using $connection   
$query3 = mysqli_query($connection2, "CALL sp_edit_data");

while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $edits_id = $row3['id'];
} // End while
```

Can anyone please help me why this unexpected behavior?
Thanks and in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I have found a solution, which might be specific to  my scenario.

My stored procs return only one row in the resultset.

So, after the CALL to the first sp and the corresponding while loop, I have simply added:

```
mysqli_next_result($connection);
```

This has removed the error message/warning I was receiving.

Anyone wants to comment whether this is the 'professional' approach?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error somewhere, causing one of the mysql functions (probably the query call(s)) to return a boolean false, which you then blindly use in a fetch call. You need to add extra error handling, e.g.

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "...") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

never assume a query has succeeded.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply; but like I said, when I provide a second $connection (called $connection2 in the above example), this error disappears. So, what might be going wrong?. By the way, I have also changed CALL to a simple SELECT * FROM etc. but still the same behavior.

Comment: probably you've got a query left opened in unbuffered mode, which mysqli defaults to - running a second query while the first one is still open results in an error, and you have no error handling. opening a second connection bypasses the error.

Comment: If the sp return only a single row, do you think the problems you described in the above comment can still occur? Also, I have added `code` mysqli_store_result($connection); but still no change.

Comment: can you please tell me what I need to do (or what function to use) to 'close' the query?

Comment: Also, if I am using a `while` loop to read results (as in the code above), should it not be retrieving the complete resultset?

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereafter the query is finished, you must close the `$connection` then for another query, connect and assign the `$connection` again.

```
mysqli_close($connection);

$connection=mysqli_connect(bla,bla,bla,bla).
```